# AuthorizationException: <exception str() failed> on Scan

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to run what seems like a very simple Scan but I'm running into an odd exception. It seems like the generator created by the scan hits an exception and I have no idea why. I tried wrapping the interior of my for loop in a try/except but it still throws the exception so I'm guessing it dies when hitting es. Here is what I've got if you can help identify what is going on:

```
old_stuff_query = {"query": {"filtered": {
    "filter": {
        "range": {
            "expire_on": {'lte': datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=53)}}

    }}}}

scanResp = scan(client=es, query=old_stuff_query, scroll="1m", index="myIndex", doc_type="myDoc")
counter = 0
for resp in scanResp:
    try:
        print("YAH")
    except:
        print("BOO")
```

But I get the following:

```
    for resp in scanResp:
  File "/home/will/.virtualenvs/side_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 314, in scan
    client.clear_scroll(body={'scroll_id': [scroll_id]}, ignore=(404, ))
  File "/home/will/.virtualenvs/side_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/will/.virtualenvs/side_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 688, in clear_scroll
    params=params, body=body)
  File "/home/will/.virtualenvs/side_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/will/.virtualenvs/side_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 84, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status_code, raw_data)
  File "/home/will/.virtualenvs/side_project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 113, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.AuthorizationException: <exception str() failed>
```

The most frustrating part is this happens completely at random. It has error'd out after less than 10k docs and more than 250k docs. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and it seems to be unicode handling that is causing it, probably because of Python2/python3 compatibility I added (with future). In pure python2.7 it seems to works.

Answer (score 3):

So I also had the same error and found the reason:
If you create a own class with special `__str__`, and in this method or a other called method throw an error with the instance from what it tries to make a string, the error message will be swap out with '<exception str() failed>':

```
>>> class X:
...     def __str__(self):
...         raise ValueError(self)
... 
>>> print(X())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __str__
ValueError: <exception str() failed>
```

In your case it seems to be sloppy programming on api side.